# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Out of range value for column 'age' : value age

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc

I keep getting SQLException but I suspect that it is not the problem. Table is :

```
create table person (first varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, last varchar(30)      DEFAULT NULL, gender char(1) DEFAULT NULL, age int(4) DEFAULT NULL);
```

Insert statements:

```
insert into person values('Barack','Obama','M',54);
insert into person values('Hillary','Clinton','f',34);
```

Spark code:

```
public void test3() {
    // SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Stackoverflow").setMaster("local[4]");
    // JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    // SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
    SparkSession spark = 
    SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaALS").master("local[1]").getOrCreate();
    SQLContext context = spark.sqlContext();
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("url", "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test");
    options.put("user", "root");
    options.put("password", "lyhao1999");
    options.put("dbtable", "(select * from person where gender = 'M') as someone");

    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = context.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();
    jdbcDF.show();
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Out of range value for column 'age' : value age
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.rowprotocol.TextRowProtocol.getInternalLong(TextRowProtocol.java:348)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.rowprotocol.TextRowProtocol.getInternalInt(TextRowProtocol.java:254)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.resultset.SelectResultSet.getInt(SelectResultSet.java:985)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$7(JdbcUtils.scala:431)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$7$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:367)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I saw it during debugging：

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "age"
```

This is a code example I found on the web, and if it is an empty table, it will not be reported as an error; I tried to change the field property to varchar, but the result of the query became the field name.

| first | last | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | last | gender | age |

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by change the url from mariadb to mysql，
although i did use the mariadb.

```
    options.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spark");
```